# Command for finding the best linear model in R

Tags: r, model, linear-regression, lm

Is there a way to get R to run all possible models (with all combinations of variables in a dataset) to produce the best/most accurate linear model and then output that model?

I feel like there is a way to do this, but I am having a hard time finding the information.

Comment: how would you define the best/ most accurate linear model ?

Comment: library(leaps)                      
allmods = regsubsets(y~x1+x2+x3+x4, nbest=2, data=mydata)                  
summary(allmods)                  I think it is something like this, but I want to do it without having to input x1+x2+...

Comment: please give us `dput(mydata)`

Comment: I do not have a specific data set. I am writing a code where any table can be input and the best model (highest rsqadj value) will be output. Since different inputs will have different numbers of explanatory variables, I am looking for a code similar to what is in my previous comment, but without having to put in the specific x-variables.

Comment: Running all possible models isn't a very scientific way to proceed. You should build your models by only including explanatory variables that you think would have an effect on your response variable. Just because you have lots of data, it doesn't mean that you should include everything. Run some models `lm1 = lm(y ~x1)` and `lm2 = lm(y~x2)` and so on and then use `AIC(lm1,lm2)` to compare your models

Comment: Running all possible models is a form of exploratory data analysis. It can also be used as confirmatory data analysis by extracting the significance values of all variables in each regression, to ensure that a variable is not significant in a rare/limited case.

Answer (score 8):

There are numerous ways this could be achieved, but for a simple way of doing this I would suggest that you have a look at the `glmulti` package, which is described in detail in this paper:

- *[glmulti: An R Package for Easy Automated Model Selection with (Generalized) Linear Models](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/6303128.pdf)*

Alternatively, very simple example of the model selection as available on the [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html) website:

```
# Stepwise Regression
library(MASS)
fit <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3,data=mydata)
step <- stepAIC(fit, direction="both")
step$anova # display results
```

Or to simplify even more, you can do more *manual* model comparison:

```
fit1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data=mydata)
fit2 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=mydata)
anova(fit1, fit2)
```

Comment: I think what is wanted is the ability to compare all possible models, rather than the 'best' model found by heuristic.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started. Although you should read my comment from above. This should build you a model based on all the data in your dataset and then compare all of the models with AIC and BIC.

```
# create a NULL vector called model so we have something to add our layers to
model=NULL

# create a vector of the dataframe column names used to build the formula
vars = names(data)
# remove variable names you don’t want to use (at least
# the response variable (if its in the first column)
vars = vars[-1]

# the combn function will run every different combination of variables and then run the glm
for(i in 1:length(vars)){
  xx = combn(vars,i)
  if(is.null(dim(xx))){
    fla = paste("y ~", paste(xx, collapse="+"))
    model[[length(model)+1]]=glm(as.formula(fla),data=data)
  } else {
    for(j in 1:dim(xx)[2]){
      fla = paste("y ~", paste(xx[1:dim(xx)[1],j], collapse="+"))
      model[[length(model)+1]]=glm(as.formula(fla),data=data) 
    }
  }
}

# see how many models were build using the loop above
length(model)

# create a vector to extract AIC and BIC values from the model variable
AICs = NULL
BICs = NULL
for(i in 1:length(model)){
  AICs[i] = AIC(model[[i]])
  BICs[i] = BIC(model[[i]])
}

#see which models were chosen as best by both methods
which(AICs==min(AICs))
which(BICs==min(BICs))
```

Comment: I find the for loop difficult to understand. Is there a *apply or function(x) implementation of the above?

Comment: For the BIC, you can use Konrad's suggestion with the parameter k set to log(n), for instance step <- stepAIC(fit, direction="both", k = log(nrow(mydata)))

Answer (score 1):

I ended up running forwards, backwards, and stepwise procedures on data to select models and then comparing them based on AIC, BIC, and adj. R-sq. This method seemed most efficient. However, when I received the actual data to be used (the program I was writing was for business purposes), I was told to only model each explanatory variable against the response, so I was able to just call `lm(response ~ explanatory)` for each variable in question, since the analysis we ended up using it for wasn't worried about how they interacted with each other.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but for those who are still encountering this discussion - the package olsrr and specifically the function ols_step_all_possible exhaustively produces an ols model for all possible subsets of variables, based on an lm object (such that by feeding it with a full model you will get all possible combinations), and returns a dataframe with R squared, adjusted R squared, aic, bic, etc. for all the models. This is very helpful in finding the best predictors but it is also very much time consuming.

see https://olsrr.rsquaredacademy.com/reference/ols_step_all_possible.html

I do not recommend just "cherry picking" the best performing model, rather I would actually look at the output and choose carefully for the most reasonable outcome. In case you would want to immediately get the best performing model (by some criteria, say number of predictors and R2) you may write a function that saves the dataframe, arranges it by number of predictors and orders it by descending R2 and spits out the top result.

Answer (score 0):

The dredge() function in R also accomplishes this.

Comment: Hi @Christina. Instead of simply posting a statement as an answer show that your solution works. Otherwise this is not really helpful.